# Unix Background process STOPPED abnormally

Tags: unix, process, background, nohup

I executed a perl script in background using the following command

```
nohup perl myPerlSCript.pl >debug_log &
```

After few minutes I got the status as

> [1]+ Stopped

I wasn't expecting it to stop, nor do I know what stopped it. How can I debug this and find out why it stopped? I am actually interested in knowing the unix commands to debug.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways a process running in the background can be stopped. All of them involve one of these signals:

- `SIGSTOP`
- `SIGTSTP`
- `SIGTTOU`
- `SIGTTIN`

`SIGSTOP` is severe. It's unblockable, unignorable, unhandlable. It stops the process as surely as `SIGKILL` would kill it. The others can be handled by the background process to prevent stopping.

- A signal was sent by another process using `kill(2)`, or by the process to itself using `raise(3)` or `kill(2)`
- The process attempted to write to the terminal, and the terminal option `tostop` is enabled (see output of `stty -a`). This generates `SIGTTOU`.
- The process attempted to change the terminal modes with `tcsetattr(3)` or an equivalent `ioctl`. (These are the same modes shown by `stty`.) This generates `SIGTTOU` regardless of the current state of the `tostop` flag.
- The process attempted to read from the terminal. This generates `SIGTTIN`.

This list is probably very incomplete.

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to see which of these signals caused the `[1]+ Stopped` at least?

Comment: run it in zsh instead of bash, it will give you a more detailed message. bash prints "Stopped" for all 4 of them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using tcsh by any chance? Tcsh actually comes with a built-in nohup command that I've had lots of problems with before, seeing the exact behavior you're seeing.

Try using `/usr/bin/nohup` directly if that is the case.

Comment: No i am not using tcsh. It is bash.